# Unable to capture command exit code in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm trying to setup my first makefile and am hitting a block at step 1. In my shell script, I did this:

```
which brew | grep 'brew not found' >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    xcode-select --install
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
fi
```

This worked just fine as a bash script. After some googling, for a Makefile, I've so far come up with this one command:

```
BREW_INSTALLED = $(shell which brew | grep 'brew not found' >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $$?)
```

However, running it gets me

```
make: BREW_INSTALLED: No such file or directory
```

I'm equally unsure when I should be adding `@` to a command (seems like anything I don't want to output?).

I'm currently on `GNU Make 3.81`.

Comment: just to be sure you're not using an ancient `make`, please update your Q to include `make --version` (or maybe it is `make -v` or `make -V`) . Good luck!

Comment: @shellter Looks like I'm on 3.81. Does that count as ancient? :/

Comment: The 3.82 tag is dated Wed Jul 28 05:39:50 2010.  I would say "ancient" is accurate

Comment: Show us your makefile. It looks like you run this as a command of a recipe. This can't work since shell variable assignments cannot have spaces around the `=` and would try to run a command named `BREW_INSTALLED`.

Comment: Hmm, I guess ancient is all relative ;-) What do you get from `uname -srv` . Looks like you're getting good advice. Good luck!

Comment: Sidebar - `which` isn't POSIX-compliant, and I have run into systems that don't have it. `command -v` is more universal IIRC - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Answer (score 4):

A typical makefile would check the presence of needed tools like this:

```
BREW := $(shell which brew)

# Check if variable brew is empty
ifeq ($(BREW),)
    $(error brew not found)
else
    $(info brew found: $(BREW))
endif


all:
    @echo "Do something with brew"
    $(BREW) --version
```

Note: There must be no tabspaces in the first two indented lines.
The two *Recipe* lines if the *all* *Rule* have to be indented with tabs.

---

The `@` at the beginning of a recipe supresses echoing: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html

Comment: Oh, interesting. Specially in a case of a tool like brew, I figured my installing it if it didn't exist would make sense. For example, there are other items I install after installing prereqs. I can move to this format.

Comment: You can install it if it doesn't exist, if you want.  But that would be a different set of work.  A makefile is NOT the same as a shell script, although it can _run_ shell scripts.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess regardless of the use (I'll switch patterns as pointed out), I'm still curious why my code fails.

Answer (score 4):

There are several odds in this line:

```
BREW_INSTALLED = $(shell which brew | grep 'brew not found' >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $$?)
```

---

In case of success, *which* writes its output to stdout, in case of failure to stderr. You are trying to capture the error message on stdout.

To feed the stderr of *which* to *grep*, you would need to write

```
which brew 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'brew not found'
```

(The order of `2>&1` and `>` also matters).

But you should not rely on the specific error message of *which*.

---

But you already get the return code you want from *which*, so you don't need grep at all.

> Which returns the number of failed arguments, or -1 when no `programname' was given. 
>   https://linux.die.net/man/1/which

---

Consider using `grep -q 'expression'` to supress output instead of redirecting stdout and stderr.

> -q, --quiet, --silent
>
> Quiet; do not write anything to standard output. Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected.
>   https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep

---

And the error message you get has nothing to do with what I'm writing above. This means the shell is trying to run *BREW_INSTALLED* as command, which probably means that *make* puts it at the beginning of a new shell.
Maybe you wrote it after a tabspace? see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html

---

To capture the return code (as string!):

```
BREW_INSTALLED := $(shell which brew >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $$?)
```

Comment: Ah! I'll take a look at the `q` flag. As you pointed out, *which* is already returning a status code I can use, but I'm not sure how to suppress the actual `Error 1` being returned (eg, just capture it, not report it). Plus, it still says `BREW_INSTALLED: No such file or directory`. Is that not how you set a variable in a makefile?

Comment: You have to set it at the right place. You probably placed it after a tabspace in a *recipe*, which works differently than the rest of the makefile. Make passes it to a subshell, which can't find the find the command and returns an error, then make exits with an error.
If you set a variable with `:=` , it gets evaluated immeadiately. If you set it with `=`, it gets evaluated lazy (when actually used). 
I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I didn't realize I couldn't set a variable in a recipe. I see there are ways around it, but that explains so much. Thank you for the great explanation!

Comment: I would still keep in mind what @MadScientist pointed out: software dependency installation does not belong to a makefile. Make is about creating dependency graphs, not sequential steps.
Consider putting it into an extra script (e.g. install-dependencies.sh).
The more conventions you follow, the less documentation you have to write.
So I would still consider my first answer better than the second (consider accepting it :).

Comment: Oh, I'm definitely planning on following that pattern. I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "dependency graph", but otherwise I plan on extracting the code to a bash script and running it there.

Comment: You write rules, e.g. an executable depends on object files, object files depend on source files.

When you tell make to build the executable, it will automatically build all intermediate files, with `-j` also in parallel.

This is a great reading: http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf . But you will probably need the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#Top

Comment: Besides dependencies, make is also good for text macros, substiution, etc. But it is text oriented and does not know about numbers, so it is bad for return codes other than 'ok' or 'error'.